# ExtraData in FlatList wont't update list when changed

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I know that extraData is used to update flatlist when it changes but somehow it does not work in my case. I know I am doing something wrong but I need advice to figure that problem out.
Here is my flatList:

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      extraData={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this.renderPost}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      onEndReached={this.loadMorePosts}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.loading}
          onRefresh={this.loadNewerPosts}
        />
      }
    />
```

and here is my deleteRequest that should remove one item from this.state.data:

```
deletePost = (index) => {
console.log(this.state.data.length);
let data = this.state.data;
data.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ data: data }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.data.length);
});
```

};

I even tried to put refresh in state and to change it every time I delete item and put it as extraData but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?
This.state.data.length is changing so the data changes but flatList do not re-renders.

Comment: You could try to implement a Pull To Refresh feature if that would fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
deletePost = (index) => {
  ....
  let data = [...this.state.data]; // here is a logic
  data.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({ data: data }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.data.length);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Pull To Refresh feature try something like this:

```
  refreshFlatlist = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        refresh: true,
      },
      () => this.getDataHandler()    // whatever updates your dataArray displayed in the list
    );
    this.setState({
      refresh: false,
    });
  };
```

Now the flatlist RefreshComponent looks like this:

```
   <FlatList
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.state.refresh}
                onRefresh={this.refreshFlatlist}
              />
            }
            extraData={this.state.refresh}
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => ( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use splice. Try below snippet it's working as expected.

```js
deletePost = index => {
   const newData = this.state.data.filter((item, i) => i !== index);
   this.setState({
     data: newData,
   });
};

render(){
  return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 deletePost = (index) => {
let data = this.state.data;
data.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ data: [] }, () => {
  this.setState({ data: data });
});
```

};

Thanks all. With your solutions I came up with this idea and it works perfectly.